# Css equal count of divs per row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I need to write css rules covered next requirements:
if only 3 items: put them in one row
if 4 items: 2 items per row
if 6 items: 3 items per row
if 8 items: 4 items per row

```
<div class="container">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

```
<style>
    .container{
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
    }
    .item{
        width: 250px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

i tried to use flexbox with flex-wrap and stable value of container width but dont get it.

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: on pure css is impossible?

Comment: You could do it with :has pseudo selector, but it's not supported in Firefox yet.  Also, what about responsive behavior?  Are all of your items always a fixed size of 250px?

Comment: yes, items must have fixed width 250px

Comment: read this: https://css-tricks.com/exploring-css-grids-implicit-grid-and-auto-placement-powers/

Comment: Not sure how that article answers the question.  It's an exhaustive article about grid and different layouts, but where exactly does it include a technique that answers the OPs question?